# Is there a reason these facets of the diamonds are just rendering black/dark?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

Is there any reason that the Facets are rendering in large dark patches,[image]

Is it to do with the lighting, the facet pattern, the booleans.

Been having this problem for a while so any advice is appreciated.

File attached.

[image]

EXPANDED PREVIOUSLY ASKED QUESTION

Comment: SAME QUESTION NOT ANSWERED NOW ELLABORATED

Comment: You can edit the same question.

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. If you get no answers edit the original post and provide further details, rather than making duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Film> Transparency > Cristal render (mark it). 
Also raise the bounces.
Also make sure glossy clipping is above 10